# Flutter Array List only prints one item instead of the whole list

Tags: flutter, arraylist

I want to print each and every item in the array in a list format but it only returns one item, which is the last item. May I please get help. This is my code below.
This is what I have tried so far using the split method because I was splitting a string into array items.

```
class BarcodeItemWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  BarcodeItem item;

  BarcodeItemWidget(this.item);

    String results(){
      String result = "";
    if( barcodeFormatEnumMap[item.barcodeFormat]! == 'PDF_417'){
         result = "MVL code:" + item.text.split('%')[1] ;
         result = "Auth code:" + item.text.split('%')[2] ;
         result = "License Number:" + item.text.split('%')[3] ;
         result = "Issue Number:" + item.text.split('%')[4] ;
         result = "Disc Number:" + item.text.split('%')[5] ;
         result = "License Plate:" + item.text.split('%')[6] ;
         result = "Vehicle Registration:" + item.text.split('%')[7] ;
         result = "Vehicle Type:" + item.text.split('%')[8] ;
         result = "Make:" + item.text.split('%')[9] ;
         result = "Model:" + item.text.split('%')[10] ;
         result = "Colour:" + item.text.split('%')[11] ;
         result = "Vin Number:" + item.text.split('%')[12] ;
         result = "Engine Number:" + item.text.split('%')[13] ;
         result = "Disk Expiry:" + item.text.split('%')[14] ;

    }else{ if (barcodeFormatEnumMap[item.barcodeFormat]! == 'CODE_128'){
      result = "item code:" + item.text ;
    }

    }

    return result;

}


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[

          Row(
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Text("Barcode Type:",
                  style: TextStyle(inherit: true, color: Colors.black),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Text(
                  barcodeFormatEnumMap[item.barcodeFormat]!,
                  style: TextStyle(inherit: true, color: Colors.black),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),

          Row(
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Text(
                    results()
                ),
              ),
const barcodeFormatEnumMap = {
  BarcodeFormat.AZTEC: 'AZTEC',
  BarcodeFormat.CODABAR: 'CODABAR',
  BarcodeFormat.CODE_39: 'CODE_39',
  BarcodeFormat.CODE_93: 'CODE_93',
  BarcodeFormat.CODE_128: 'CODE_128',
  BarcodeFormat.DATA_MATRIX: 'DATA_MATRIX',
  BarcodeFormat.EAN_8: 'EAN_8',
  BarcodeFormat.EAN_13: 'EAN_13',
  BarcodeFormat.ITF: 'ITF',
  BarcodeFormat.PDF_417: 'PDF_417',
  BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE: 'QR_CODE',
  BarcodeFormat.RSS_14: 'RSS_14',

};
```

May you please check what am I doing wrong. Your help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from this  `String result = "";` you are expecting a single result
you can make it a list `List<String> result =[];`
your function will aslo return a list `List<String> results(){...`

then you can add your data to list as follows
`result.add( "MVL code:" + item.text.split('%')[1] );`

where you're displaying results

```
Row(
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Text(
                    results()
                ),
              ),
```

you need to use a `listview.builder`

```
Listview.builder( 
itemCount:results.length
itemBuilder:(_,i){
return Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Text(
                    results[i]
                ),
              )...
```

Comment: Hi Griffins, thanks for the response. Please tell me how can I use a listview.builder where I am displaying results. Thanks

Comment: hi too, i have updated answer with listview builder